# Where can i find a API for interacting with Apple Devices(via USB)?

Tags: c#, ios, api, itunes, itunes-sdk

I want to develop an iTunes alternative such as iTools,i-FunBox,...

Does Apple provide any API for this job?

Or is there any unofficial way to do this?

Please help me,Thanks for reading my question.

Note:***I know C#***So Please give me a way for doing this in
.NET framework.

*Edit:People may say i want a recommendation but i just want to know that what should i search for? iTunes API,iTunes COM what???*

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: I don't want any recommendation,I just want to say how this job is performed,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does provide an API for interacting with USB devices, namely [`IOKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000011). There is a broader discussion about working with USB devices in Apple's [USB Device Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html), which is a little dated, but still applicable and has tons of links to other resources, too.

In terms of the specific interface for Apple devices, I might suggest you start with the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html).